# is there a way to LIMIT per sub-iteration (not total)?

Tags: arangodb

I have a graph where type "petal" vertices "connect" to type "flower" vertices with edges.
Now, for every "flower" I only want to pull one "petal". They are all in one collection.
How exactly can I do that? It seems that LIMIT statement works per transaction, not per iteration.

What I am trying is

```
FOR f in Botany
FILTER type=="flower"
FOR p in 1 INBOUND f GRAPH "BotanyGraph"
LIMIT 1
RETURN p
```

But all I am getting is 1 petal, total.
How can I achieve one petal off every flower?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like that?

```
FOR f in Botany
  FILTER type == "flower"
  LET pp = (
    FOR p in 1 INBOUND f GRAPH "BotanyGraph"
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN p)
  FOR p in pp
    RETURN p
```